# C , how to create thread using pthread_create function

Tags: c, multithreading, function, pthreads, createthread

I'm making a c file for a dispatch queue that gets a task and put it in to a queue which is the linked list. In order to do this, I need to create threads using

```
pthread_t cThread;
if(pthread_create(&cThread, NULL, work, param)){
    perror("ERROR creating thread.");
}
```

However I need to make another function that goes into 'work' and 'param' variable as parameters of create function. My friend told me that I just need to put any code in the work function that loops infinitely so the thread does not die.. Can anyone explain each parameter goes in to the `pthread_create` function- especially for `work` and `param`? I searched Google for this, but most of tutorials are so hard to understand the concept...

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html

Comment: yea i read that. I just want someone to explain me in sentences- what each parameter is for

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The four parameters to `pthread_create` are, in order:

1. A pointer to a `pthread_t` structure, which `pthread_create` will fill out with information on the thread it creates.
2. A pointer to a `pthread_attr_t` with parameters for the thread. You can safely just pass `NULL` most of the time.
3. A function to run in the thread. The function must return `void *` and take a `void *` argument, which you may use however you see fit. (For instance, if you're starting multiple threads with the same function, you can use this parameter to distinguish them.)
4. The `void *` that you want to start up the thread with. Pass `NULL` if you don't need it.

Answer (score 25):

clarifying duskwuff's answer:

`work` parameter is a function pointer.  The function should take one argument which is indicated as type `void *` and return value `void *`.

`param` is expected to be a pointer to the data that `work` will receive.

As an example, lets say you want to pass two int to the worker.  Then, you can create something like this:

```
int *param = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
param[0] = 123;
param[1] = 456;
pthread_create(&cThread, NULL, work, param);
```

Then your work function can convert the pointer type and grab the param data:

```
void *work(void * parm) {
    int *param = (int *)parm;
    int first_val = param[0];
    ....
}
```

You can do more complex stuff, like creating a struct with all of the data you need to pass.

Comment: Please don't cast return values from `malloc`. Its return is `void*` and is always assignable to any data pointer. Same goes for `parm`.

Comment: @Jens If you are using C++, then you **must** explicitly cast return values from `malloc`, or the code won't compile. If you are using C, then it is optional.

Comment: @lingjiankong the OP is labelled "c".  I don't want to see c++ artifacts in a c answer.  It is hard enough with the similar language names, let's not make it any more difficult!